# Excel formula with diagonal

Tags: excel, diagonal

I have a question for executing quickly.

[image]

`A1:C3` is original. I want to create a new based on it and `F1:F3`.
`A8` is `A3 / F1`.
`A7` is `A2 / F2`.
`A6` is `A1 / F3`.
`B7` is `B2 / F1`.
`B6` is `B1 / F2`.
`C6` is `C1 / F1`.

I want to use formula to do this rather than input `A8 = A3/F1`. And do it many times in each cells.

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula should do it:

```
=IF(A1<>"",A1/INDEX($F$1:$F$3,1+(ROW()-ROW($A$6)+COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$6))),"")
```

You have to put it in A6 and copy it to the other cells.

(@Rob Gale: ok :-) )

First you have to check for empty cells (`A1<>""`).

Then the numerator of the division is simply a reference and can easily copied between the formulas (`A1`).

The tricky one is the nominator. The sum of the row and column offsets of the respective cell is calculated and used as index into the 'percentage range' in column F.

Comment: Great solution @Fratyx. Perhaps a little explanation of the formula you used:

Answer (score 0):

1. Select `A6:C8`
2. Press <kbd>F2</kbd>
3. Copy and paste this formula

`=CHOOSE({1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9},A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2,A3,B3,C3)/CHOOSE({3,2,1;2,1,1;1,1,1},F1,F2,F3,F1,F2,F3,F1,F2,F3)`

4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Sorry about the type. It should be `A6:C8`